# AdjustResize on jetpack compose not working

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-jetpack-compose, window-soft-input-mode, adjustpan

I'm implementing a screen on my project using jetpack compose (1.0.0-beta09) but I'm facing a issue on a screen with a footer that need to be always visible, even the keyboard is opened, I know that we have 'adjustResize' on android that solve this problem in a normal activity (I've a lot of screens with this footer type and it's working), but on compose if I put adjustResize on manifest or on the onCreate method of the activity the keyboard continue hiding the footer:

That's my screen without the keyboard opened, just to figure what I'm talking about

[image: That's my screen without the keyboard opened, just to figure what I'm talking about]

And that's the screen with the keyboard opened

[image: And that's the screen with the keyboard opened]

The manifest activity tag, I'm trying to open the screen with the keyboard already opened and the footer visible above him:

```html
<activity
            android:name=".presentation.creation.billing.NewBookingBillingActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeBase.Compose"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"/>
```

onCreate method:

```html
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        injectFeature()
        initView()

        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
        
        setContent {
            BuildScreen()
        }
    }
```

I know that's redundant use setSoftInputMode on manifest and on onCreate, but I'm trying anything.

-

My screen compose scope:

```html
Column(fillMaxSize){
 - AppBar
 - Box(fillMaxSize){
      //lazycolumn used to enable scroll with bottom padding to prevent last item to be hided below the footer
     - LazyColumn(fillMaxSize | contentPadding) {
        //TextFields of the screen
     }
    
    //footer
     - Box(fillMaxWidth | height 53 | align.centerBottom){
        //footer content
     }
     
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the Insets library that deals with this? https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 8):

I guess the problem is in your `LazyColumn` modifier.
if you set `weight` to 1f. It will work.

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {})
    LazyColumn(Modifier.weight(1f)) {

    }
    Row {
       Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
           Text(text = "Ok")
       }
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: weight has been removed, any way to do this nowadays?

Comment: The answer above still working on compose 1.2.0-beta02. The weight modifier was not removed... :/

Comment: You are right, got a cached old version :(

Answer (score 3):

Found the perfect answer for this.
In v1.8.0 or above compose we can just add below line to main composable

```
Modifier.imePadding()
```