# Stop the keyboard pushing the top app bar off the screen in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Compose activity, where there's a top app bar, and some `TextFields` towards the bottom of the screen. When I focus on one of the `TextFields` and the keyboard is invoked, I want the text field to appear above the keyboard, so I can see what I'm typing. This works fine, however the whole screen content is pushed upwards making the top app bar disappear or be cut off at the top.

I think ideally, the top app bar would be pinned to the top, and only the contents below would shift. It doesn't matter if the top app bar is part of the scaffold, or above the scaffold in a `Column`:

```kotlin
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar("...")
        }
    ) {
        // scrollable contents with TextFields
    }

---> OR

    Column {
        TopAppBar("...")
        Scaffold {
            // scrollable contents with TextFields
        }
    }
```

This is the unwanted behaviour illustrated:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve my desired behaviour of pinning the top app bar? Should the top app bar be pushed up by default in Compose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have to specify a weight to one of your composable.

Taking some reference from an answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68440573/adjustresize-on-jetpack-compose-not-working). Assuming you have set `adjustResize` in your manifest,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

you can consider this as a rough solution

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(title = { Text("Hello World")})
    }
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(it)
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .background(Color.Gray)
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .background(Color(0xFF6f4d8c)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = "User Name",
                onValueChange = {}
            )
        }

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .background(Color(0xFF6286bd)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = "Password",
                onValueChange = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I just put some colors to show how the widgets occupy the space in their parent Column.

Comment: Thank you, I think `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize` is what I was missing actually - as long as the text field is visible on the screen, but the resizing doesn't affect the top app bar, it's all good!

Answer (score 2):

Summarize:
There are four options for the softInputMode which controls the soft keyboard or others:

1. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_UNSPECIFIED
   (Determined by the systems)
2. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE / SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED
   (Calculate size and adapt)
3. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
   (Move as a whole)
4. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING
   (Do nothing)

So the solution is setting adjustResize in your manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

but sometimes you must to write this at the `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

**BUI IF YOU WANT TO USE `Scaffold`**
The best way is write

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING)
```

and add this to the content of Scaffold

```
Modifier.navigationBarsPadding()
```

add this to TextField

```
Modifier.imePadding()
```

It has been bothering me for a long time...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
        window.setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING
        );
        setContent { /* Composable Content */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this makes the content static, so that when the keyboard is invoked it covers the text field